# Parsing tabular data using grok filter (Logstash)

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a log file that has data in tabular format like this:

```
First name     Middle Name    Last name

A              B              C
D              E              F
G              H              I
```

I want to get the parsed output of this log in a JSON format as follows:

```
[{
    "First name": "A",
    "Middle name": "B",
    "Last name": "C"
}, {
    "First name": "D",
    "Middle name": "E",
    "Last name": "F"
}, {
    "First name": "G",
    "Middle name": "H",
    "Last name": "I"
}]
```

How do I parse it using a Grok filter? Or, are there any other filters that can help me achieve the same? Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Is there anything that works at least partially for you?

Comment: Split on [`[ ]{2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/2ozt9t/1/) and see how far you come.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if your end goal is at all possible, because Logstash operates on single log events and not on a whole file (those it will not be possible to surround all log events with `[` and `]` for the json array.

But you should come quite close with the [csv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html). You could use a config like this (columns separated by tabulators):

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path/to/file"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
    separator => "\t"
    columns => [ "First name", "Middle name", "Last name" ]
  }
}
output {
  file {
    codec => json
    path => "/path/to/file"
  }
}
```

As an alternative you could also use the `json_lines` codec for the output.